# Get started with Firebase Admin Sdk using java

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication, aws-lambda, firebase-admin

I have built an Android application that uses email/password authentication. But now I want to switch to custom Authentication method like `customTokens`.

While googling, I came across this *Admin SDK Setup* in Firebase using NodeJS and Java.

I don't know how to setup the Firebase Admin SDK. I have gone through the instructions, but I can't understand it, although I have setup the Admin panel, I can't understand the concept of a *Server App*.

When I have tried to copy the dependency given in the instructions to my client side app, it started giving an error -- i.e. it's unable to  recognize the *Auth methods* that I have used to Authenticate the user using email/password authentication.

And when I copied the snippet from the instruction in my `Application.java` file where I initiate Firebase:

```
FirebaseOptions options = new FirebaseOptions.Builder()
  .setServiceAccount(new FileInputStream("path/to/serviceAccountKey.json"))
  .setDatabaseUrl("https://<DATABASE_NAME>.firebaseio.com/")
  .build();

FirebaseApp.initializeApp(options);
```

`.setServiceAccount()` doesn't get recognize it -- i.e. it shows in red.

So bottom line is I don't know how to use Admin SDK. What is the function of this? Where to deploy the code in order to use Admin SDK?

I want to mint custom tokens for SMS verification for which I want to use Amazon Lambda. I really don't know where to get started or don't know any tutorials.

Comment: Can you check your import statements and see if correct classes are imported? Also check if you have downloaded the latest JDK? I'm using 4.0.3.

Comment: These are my Imports Statements `
import com.firebase.client.Firebase;
import com.firebase.client.Logger;
import com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp;
import com.google.firebase.FirebaseOptions;

import java.io.FileInputStream;`

Comment: So this means that I have to integrate this code in my Client-Side app of firebase....Right??? And If I do so my Normal Firebase Authentication method will not work I suppose, Only CustomAuthentication will work...Right???

Comment: Import statements seem to be fine. And this Admin SDK is not for Client Side but is meant to be for Server Side. I'm quite frustrated with the documentation & support myself but being a free user, cant complain :D. Which Editor are you using? Have you tried to still compile and run the code?

Comment: Server Side?? I am using at a client side....in Android Studio.....I don't know about server side....I mean if I use "Amazon AWS Lambda" server then I should imbed this code over  there...on their server...or what please explain

Comment: For Android, you have Firebase Android SDK https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup and the Admin SDK is for Backend services (You can still use it though to make a device based app with Admin functionality).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130063/discussion-between-oswald-and-ssg).